# F# type inference less generic than indicated by the type annotations

Tags: generics, f#, type-inference

In the last line of the following code snippet, I get two warnings: `This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'c has been constrained to be type ''a'.` and `This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'b has been constrained to be type ''a * 'a'.`

```
type SomeBaseClass<'a> () =
    class end

type SomeClass<'a when 'a:equality> (getValue:unit->'a, ?arg2:SomeBaseClass<'b>) =
    inherit SomeBaseClass<'a*'a>()

    member this.Value with get () = getValue ()

    member this.Transform (transformation:'a->'c) =
        let func ():'c = transformation this.Value
        SomeClass<'c> (func, this) // warnings are attached to this line
```

This, on the other hand, compiles without issue:

```
type SomeOtherClass<'a when 'a:equality> (getValue:unit->'a) =
    inherit SomeBaseClass<'a*'a>()

    member this.Value with get () = getValue ()

    member this.Transform (transformation:'a->'c) =
        let func ():'c = transformation this.Value
        SomeOtherClass<'c> func
```

I don't see anything preventing `transformation` from returning a different type than it gets passed. I also don't see why that second warning is even a warning because it's obviously already my intention for the `'b` type parameter of the new instance to be `'a*'a`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic type `SomeClass` is using a generic argument `'b` in its constructor that is missing in its definition. Changing the type definition to

```
type SomeClass<'a, 'b when 'a:equality> ...
```

and the line with the warning to

```
    SomeClass(func, this)
```

removes the error, and the returned class is of type `SomeClass<'c, ('a * 'a)>`.

*I have no idea what this is trying to achieve though, so I can't tell whether this is a sensible correction.*

Comment: That does clear up the warning but it has the side effect of making every instance of SomeClass have two type parameters instead of one which is not the added complexity I'm looking for with an optional parameter that isn't stored as an instance field. Is there a way to give the constructor a type argument that the class itself doesn't have or do I have to use a static function or something instead?

Comment: @Flaise `SomeClass` should normally have two type parameters if its constructor has them. Imagine an expression like `Array.zeroCreate<'b> 8` somewhere in the type; its result would not be properly defined in F#'s type system without the second type argument defined. But, the exact type of `SomeClass` can often be inferred. I edited the answer, so that it omits the type arguments in the constructor call. Of course, this is less likely to work if one of the parameters is optional; the second type would have to be clear from other context than the constructor.

Comment: So I can't parameterize /just/ the constructor - the constructor takes the same type arguments as the entire class? I'll just use a static function since .NET saves that type information at runtime, which interferes with debugging and performance.